# Is there a way to know which carrier locked the android phone using ADB

Tags: android, adb, gsm

How to get a name of a carrier that locked the android device using adb commands. I've tried with these commands so far

```
adb shell
getprop | grep brand
```

but some devices return only manufacture company and others return manufacture company as well as carrier name. Is there any commands that are reliable?

Comment: I am not sure if you will find the name, but may be Mobile Country Codes (MCC) or Mobile Network Codes (MNC). I would assume that these are the values that specify what SIM card is acceptable and on SIM-card level these two values define the mobile network provider. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mobile_country_code and https://www.mcc-mnc.com